# Creating dynamic variables or arrays to have flexible code

Tags: jquery

For each model of car in my database I would like to have a separate array where I can manipulate the info of each model. For example, if I have 2 models in the DB I should create 2 arrays each for each model. Example:

```
mercedes_array = {
    "Shop": "", 
    "Saling": ""
}
BMW_array = {
    "Shop": "", 
    "Saling": ""
}
```

If a new model is added to the DB (eg `KIA`) I have to go to my code and add, `KIA_array = {}`

Is there a way to do this? I don't have any idea honestly. I would like to have flexible code, where whatever is added to the DB is not necessary to add a new variable in the code.

Comment: instead do something like: `[{"CARS":[{"BMW":{KEY:VAL}}.....]}]`

Comment: refer to basics of OOP

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery as a JS library you can do it using constructor function, which will give you an opportunity to create each new car using this common constructor properties.

```
function Car(brand, model, price, speed) {
    this.brand = brand;
    this.model = model;
    this.price = price;
    this.speed = speed;
}

var jacksCar = new Car('Toyota', 'Corolla', 18000, 180);
```